# QQmlEngine singleton double free

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

for using a QQmlEngine singleton in multiple qquickwindow , qquickwidget,qquickview,
(if each window create a QQmlEngine, you will have to set plugins path, import qmldir path ,..etc again and again)
i store QQmlEngine singleton into  my ioc container. it's a  std::shared_ptr in template class;

when i exit app.exec();  then error :

```
*** Error in `path to my executeable': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000029df190 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
.
.
.
my ioc container backtrace...
.
.
.
============================
```

my code is:

```
{

    auto p_engine = IocContainer::get()->ResolveObject<QQmlEngine>().get();
    QQmlComponent component(p_engine);

    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    auto url = transUrl("qrc:/dv_qmlLib/Window/QmlDebugWindow.qml");
    component.loadUrl(url);
    if ( component.isReady() )
    {
        QEventLoop loop;
        auto a =   component.create();
        qmlDebugWindow* win =  reinterpret_cast<qmlDebugWindow*>(a);
        QObject::connect(win,&QQuickWindow::closing,&loop,[&](auto* p){
            Q_UNUSED(p)
            if(win->isClosed())
                loop.exit();
        });

        if(onWinCreated)
            onWinCreated(win);
        win->setLoadUrl(qmlUrl);

        loop.exec();
        loop.disconnect(win);
        win->deleteLater();
    }
    else
        qWarning() << component.errorString();

}
```

but i don't know where is  the first destroy method called;

print  `QQmlEngine::objectOwnerShip` indicte it owner is cpp;

i also test QQmlApplicationEngine , it has a same error:double free.

have one meeted this error ?

i want to using a QQmlEninge singleton in my application.  (base on qwidgets, but have some qquickwindow, qquickwidget, and their are using qml library) ,and when app exit , QQmlEngine singleton will not double free;

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` destroys the owned object, that's the point of using it. Why don't you just store a pointer? Anyway it's too hard to answer such a question without [mcve]

Comment: finally, i custom share_ptr's deletor,  replace default to qobject::deletelater()

Comment: but remember: wrong decision leads to workarounds that lead to escalation of wrong decisions 

Comment: It may be because I created a qcomponent with qqmlengine and instantiated it as a window, and there is an implicit behavior that causes qmlengine to be parsed by the qt framework when the program exits.  i updated my code to this question .  if my code have not runed,  qmlengine will only destory once.